# Using TiledTextureAtlas to animate particles?

Tags: android, andengine

I am using a PointParticleEmitter to make particles starting at a specific point. However, I want these particles to be animated.

I created a BitmapTextureAtlas from a tiled atlas:

```
/*
 * Create the bitmap texture atlas for the sprite's texture region
 */
BuildableBitmapTextureAtlas mBitmapTextureAtlas = new BuildableBitmapTextureAtlas(
        mEngine.getTextureManager(), 1024, 1024, TextureOptions.BILINEAR);

/*
 * Create the sprite's texture region via the
 * BitmapTextureAtlasTextureRegionFactory
 */

mTextureRegion = BitmapTextureAtlasTextureRegionFactory.createTiledFromAsset(
        mBitmapTextureAtlas, c, getSpriteFileName(), 8 , 8);

/* Build the bitmap texture atlas */
try
{
    mBitmapTextureAtlas
            .build(new BlackPawnTextureAtlasBuilder<IBitmapTextureAtlasSource, BitmapTextureAtlas>(
                    0, 0, 0));
}
catch (TextureAtlasBuilderException e)
{
    e.printStackTrace();
}
/*
 * Load the bitmap texture atlas into the device's gpu memory
 */
mBitmapTextureAtlas.load();
```

However when I attach the textureRegion to the particleSystem, it doesn't animate:

```
BatchedSpriteParticleSystem particleSystem = new BatchedSpriteParticleSystem(
        particleEmitter, minSpawnRate, maxSpawnRate, maxParticleCount, mTextureRegion,
        engine.getVertexBufferObjectManager());
```

Comment: First test "mTextureRegion" with  animated sprite.If it is not working then it be problem with your texture. If it is working fine then it  be problem with your particle effect.

Comment: It works with animated sprite, but the thing is animatedsprite has all these parameters where I can tell it how long to play each frame. However, I'm not sure how to give this information to the particlesystem

Comment: If you check "BatchedSpriteParticleSystem" class they haven't implemented anything for "ITiledTextureRegion" which can return array of ITextureRegions.So i think it may not work.

Comment: if you want, you can edit "BatchedSpriteParticleSystem" class as per requirement